# Cross-referencing to included PDF with counter and argument in the label

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I would like to use the following code for including PDF documents in my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xargs}                                          


%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   % Macro to find the number of pages of included PDF document
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcounter{imagepage}
\newcommand*{\foreachpage}[2]{
  \begingroup
   \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \xdef\foreachpage@num{\the\pdflastximagepages}
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{imagepage}{0} 
  \@whilenum\value{imagepage}<\foreachpage@num\do{
    \stepcounter{imagepage}
    #2\relax
  }
}
\makeatother


%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   % Macro to include PDF document with page numbers in caption and label
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommandx{\picTEST}[5][1=0.9, 2=0]
{
    \foreachpage{#4}
 {
  \begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=#1\hsize,page=\value{imagepage},angle=#2]{#4}}
   \label{#3\theimagepage}
     \caption{#5 - Page \arabic{imagepage} of {\the\pdflastximagepages}}
  \end{figure}
  \clearpage
 }  
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Some Text}
Here is reference to page \ref{Document1_Label_Page3} of the included PDF document.

\newpage
\section{Some insert of PDF document}
\picTEST{Document1_Label_Page}{Document1.pdf}{Document1}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the label in the text does not expand as a number '3', but I get '??' instead. However, when I click on '??' in the text, the cross-referencing to the page number 3 of the included PDF document works well - it jumps to this page (or better say to this figure).
I suppose the problem is in the second macro `\picTEST` where I use `\label{#3\theimagepage}` and maybe in the text where I am referencing `\ref{Document1_Label_Page3}`. I would very kindly ask for support. Please use some example multi page PDF document named `Document1.pdf`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's difficult to test your code, as we don't have `Document1.pdf` etc. at hand.

Comment: There are two 'errors'... First: Use `\label` after `\caption` and you are referring to page `3` (as far as I understand it, but does your document have a page `3` at all?)

Comment: I wonder, if this feature could not be achieved more easily with `pdfpages` package?

Comment: `pdfpages` does not do the job in my case since, if I am not mistaken, it simply attaches the PDF document without keeping the defined layout (header, footer, etc.) of the main tex document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\label` command in the `\picTEST` macro must come after `\caption`, as it needs a `\refstepcounter` call, which is done within `\caption`. Otherwise the label points to something different or to nowhere.

Furthermore, the document must have the corresponding number of pages which should be referred to.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xargs}                                          


%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   % Macro to find the number of pages of included PDF document
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcounter{imagepage}
\newcommand*{\foreachpage}[2]{
  \begingroup
   \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \xdef\foreachpage@num{\the\pdflastximagepages}
    \endgroup
  \setcounter{imagepage}{0} 
  \@whilenum\value{imagepage}<\foreachpage@num\do{%
    \stepcounter{imagepage}
    #2\relax
  }
}
\makeatother


%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   % Macro to include PDF document with page numbers in caption and label
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommandx{\picTEST}[5][1=0.9, 2=0]
{
  \foreachpage{#4}
 {
   \begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
     \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=#1\hsize,page=\value{imagepage},angle=#2]{#4}}
     \caption{#5 - Page \arabic{imagepage} of {\the\pdflastximagepages}}
     \label{#3\theimagepage}
   \end{figure}
   \clearpage
 }  
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Some Text}
Here is reference to page \ref{Document1_Label_Page3} of the included PDF document.

\newpage
\section{Some insert of PDF document}
\picTEST{Document1_Label_Page}{quickcode.pdf}{Document1}

\end{document}
```

## quickcode.tex

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{loopcounter}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < 11}{%
\blindtext[\number\value{loopcounter}]
\newpage
}%



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such a simple mistake... Well, devil in the details. Thank a lot for help.