# How do I prevent the section heading from printing 3 times in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I used the code from [Cross-referencing to included PDF with counter and argument in the label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209927/cross-referencing-to-included-pdf-with-counter-and-argument-in-the-label) and also from [Bates numbering of multiple pdfs with label reference to the page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273545/bates-numbering-of-multiple-pdfs-with-label-reference-to-the-page-numbers).

In my quest for bates numbering, all now seems to work with exception of the toc:

[image]

The sections look good, as follows:

[image]

The LaTeX code I used (using the quickcode.tex document in [The first reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209927/cross-referencing-to-included-pdf-with-counter-and-argument-in-the-label) to create pdfs 10.pdf and 18.pdf) to make the examples follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xargs}                                          

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   % Macro to include PDF document with page numbers in caption and label
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{imagepage}

\makeatletter
\newcommandx{\picTEST}[5][1=0.9, 2=0]
{\pdfximage{#4}
\setcounter{imagepage}{0} 
\@whilenum\value{imagepage}<\pdflastximagepages\do{%
    \stepcounter{imagepage}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,page=\value{imagepage},angle=#2]{#4}
     \caption{#5 - Page \arabic{imagepage} of {\the\pdflastximagepages}}
     \label{#3\theimagepage}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ORDINALstring{section} POINT}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\usepackage{xpatch} \makeatletter 
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname \@mkboth}{\LARGE\uppercase\contentsname\@mkboth}{}{} 
\makeatother


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}


\begin{document}

\Large
\clearpage
\begingroup
\areaset{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{RECORD PAGE}
\picTEST{Transcript1_Label_Page}{10.pdf}{Transcript, September 1, 2010}
\picTEST{Transcript2_Label_Page}{18.pdf}{Transcript, February 23, 2011}


\endgroup

\tableofcontents

\newpage

 \setcounter{page}{1}

 \section{~} 

\subsection{All Cows Eat Grass}

Here is reference to page \ref{Transcript2_Label_Page3} of the included PDF document, proving that:

The grass is greener...
\section{~}
```

]5

So, if anyone knows how to eliminate the repeating section headings in the table of contents, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also get a bunch of errors, so the output is essentially arbitrary.

The command `\ORDINALstring` is fragile, but, more importantly, it is not fully expandable. So you have to use `\ORDINALstringnum{\arabic{section}}` after having robustified the `fmtcount` command:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % loaded by xpatch
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ORDINALstringnum{\arabic{section}} POINT}
\robustify{\ORDINALstringnum}
```

You're better to load all packages first, then apply the customizations.

Also note that issuing `\Large` at the beginning is not the best thing to do. The results will not be satisfying at all. Also using `\pdfximage` directly doesn't seem very portable.

Finally `\uppercase\contentsname` is a very good way to look for trouble, as `\uppercase` is not a macro taking an argument. It should be

```
\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}
```

I have also fixed the order of package loading.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xargs}                                          
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   % Macro to include PDF document with page numbers in caption and label
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{imagepage}

\makeatletter
\newcommandx{\picTEST}[5][1=0.9, 2=0]
{\pdfximage{#4}
\setcounter{imagepage}{0} 
\@whilenum\value{imagepage}<\pdflastximagepages\do{%
    \stepcounter{imagepage}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,page=\value{imagepage},angle=#2]{#4}
     \caption{#5 - Page \arabic{imagepage} of {\the\pdflastximagepages}}
     \label{#3\theimagepage}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ORDINALstringnum{\arabic{section}} POINT}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\robustify{\ORDINALstringnum}

\makeatletter 
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname \@mkboth}{\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}\@mkboth}{}{} 
\makeatother


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\Large
\areaset{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{RECORD PAGE}
\picTEST{Transcript1_Label_Page}{example-image.pdf}{Transcript, September 1, 2010}
\picTEST{Transcript2_Label_Page}{example-image.pdf}{Transcript, February 23, 2011}

\endgroup

\tableofcontents

\newpage

 \setcounter{page}{1}

 \section{~} 

\subsection{All Cows Eat Grass}

Here is reference to page \ref{Transcript2_Label_Page3} of the included PDF document, proving that:

The grass is greener...
\section{~}

\end{document}
```

[image]